# Delayed Job DeserializationError, failed to load: allocator undefined for Proc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

With version 4 of `delayed_job_active_record` gem, I want to delay requests to an external API. My job is added to database, and `rake jobs:work` runs it and removes it from the database.  However, the actual delayed code from my `messages_controller.rb` is never executed.

If I try to `Delayed::Job.last.invoke_job` in the rails console, I receive the following error:

```
Delayed::DeserializationError: Job failed to load: allocator undefined for Proc. Handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject: !ruby/object:MyApp::Zendesk\n  client: !ruby/object:ZendeskAPI::Client\n    config: !ruby/object:ZendeskAPI::Configuration\n      client_options: {}\n      cache: !ruby/object:ZendeskAPI::LRUCache\n        size: 1000\n        store: {}\n        lru: []\n      url: https://redacted.zendesk.com/api/v2\n      username: redacted\n      password: redacted\n      retry: true\n      logger: !ruby/object:Logger\n        progname: \n        level: 0\n        default_formatter: !ruby/object:Logger::Formatter\n          datetime_format: \n        formatter: \n        logdev: !ruby/object:Logger::LogDevice\n          shift_size: \n          shift_age: \n          filename: \n          dev: !ruby/object:IO {}\n          mutex: !ruby/object:Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex\n            mon_owner: \n            mon_count: 0\n            mon_mutex: !ruby/object:Mutex {}\n    callbacks:\n    - !ruby/object:Proc {}\n    resource_cache: {}\nmethod_name: :create_support_ticket\nargs:\n- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters\n  name: redacted\n  email: redacted\n  reason: General\n  message: test\n"
```

The code trying to be run is the `create_support_ticket` method:

```
# messages_controller.rb
require 'zendesk'

class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  layout "application"

  # /suport/contact-us
  def contact_us
    zendesk = MyApp::Zendesk.new
    zendesk.delay.create_support_ticket(params[:message])

    # render page
    respond_to do |format|
      flash[:notice] = "Email sent successfully!" if @sent
      format.html { render "pages/support/contact-us" }
    end
  end
end

# zendesk.rb
require 'zendesk_api'

module MyApp
  class Zendesk
    attr_accessor :client

    def initialize(*args)
      @client = create_client
    end

    # contact-us ticket methods
    def create_support_ticket(params={})
      unless params.blank? || @client.blank?
        # get or create user_id for submitter
        params[:requester_id] = check_user_exists(params)

        begin
          ticket = @client.tickets.create(
            subject: "Support Ticket",
            comment: { value: params[:message] },
            submitter_id: params[:requester_id],
            requester_id: params[:requester_id],
            assignee_id: 201578811,
            status: "new",
            fields: [
              {id: 20887016, value: "Support"},
              {id: 20966436, value: "New"}])
          return ticket
        rescue => e
          Airbrake.notify e
        end
      else
        return false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DelayedJob tries to serialize the object you are calling the method on.

In your case, that object has an IO and also a Proc object. Both of them are not compatible with serialization. Best thing you can do is writing a simple wrapper that has no dependencies and initializes all the stuff inside the method-call.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to come across the same issue as above. I had an object of Oauth::Client which failed to deserialize by delayed_job Gem.

To resolve, I have changed my approach, so that the Ouath::Client object isn't serialized/deserialized when I add a method to the delayed job.